# Text shows big numbers in exponential form

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple message box with a slider. The slider controls the displayed number. The numbers can get quite big. When they do the `Text` component shows it in standard form (see below).

[image: Text shows 4.0E+14]

How do I stop it from doing that?

**Edit:**

Let's say the maximum number can be up to 100 Quadrillions (100000000000000000)

How the text is set:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class SliderMessageBox : MonoBehaviour
{
  public Slider SliderObject;
  public Text SliderFeedback;

  public void Function(Long MaximumValue)
  {
    SliderObject.minValue = 1000;
    SliderObject.maxValue = MaximumValue;
    SliderObject.onValueChanged.AddListener(SetFeedback);
    SetFeedback(SliderObject.value);
  }

  void SetFeedback(float value)
  {
    SliderFeedback.text = value.ToString();
  }
}
```

The public parameters are set via the inspector. This is not the whole class, just the part concerning the feedback *(and it's a little bit modified to make sense.)*

Comment: What is the range values produced by the slider and please include piece of code of how you are setting the slider values to the text...

Comment: What's the min and max of the slider and the default value?

Comment: @Programmer the min value's `1000`, the max varies. it can take up to `100 Quad`. Default value's actually `Value`

Comment: @Programmer added some code lines. And I made it more similar to the actual code

Comment: Ok. I  am checking why that is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is from `value.ToString()` line of code.You can provide which format to use to the `value.ToString();`  function parameter and that format will be used to convert the float to `string`. Since this is a large `float`, you lose precision.

To get full value like `40797490000000000`

```
SliderFeedback.text = value.ToString("#");
```

Get the values in  `42,225,940,000,000,000` format

```
SliderFeedback.text = value.ToString("#,#");
```

You can also use `N` (`value.ToString("N1");`). to include decimal places. `N2` for 2 decimal places, `N3` for 3 decimal places... This can also be donw ith `#.##`. Visit [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information about Standard numeric format strings.